# In JS Cannot read property 'style' of null, but when copying and pasting code it works fine

Tags: javascript, html, css, null, syntax-error

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but i get a error in this [pen](https://codepen.io/ItsEvanB/pen/MWwYWoQ). I am assuming I just put something in the wrong place, but help and a description of what I did wrong would be appreciated

```js
  function on() {
  document.getElementById('about').style.display ="block";
}

function off() {
  document.getElementById('about').style.display ="none";
}
```

```css
.about {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  background-color: #ffffff;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Scaledish</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="https://preview.redd.it/y50x69der7h31.png?width=960&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=9179a708e2b531b3b89eed861c75d04375e6510b" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <div class="SlideContent">
    <div class="about"
    <div class="home">
      <div class="TxtC">
        <div class="ctxt">
          <div class="TextHead">
            Scaledish 
          </div>
          <div class="TextBodyTW">
            <a onclick='on()'>About</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You didn't close the tag on line 10 in your pen. You got this kind of error because you are trying to get an element by id, but you wrote a class, which needs a different method. Just use `document.querySelector('.about')` and this method actually accept CSS selector as an argument.

Comment: Thank you for that idea! Dunno what happened on line 10, just copied and pasted to code pen from atom, which does not have that issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can see two problems there:

1 - You have a tag that is missing the `>`:

```
<div class="about"
```

2 - Your JavaScript is looking for an element with an id attribute, but your div has only a class attribute. You could try:

```
// Get all elements with the class about, and then go to the first element of the array
document.getElementsByClassName("about")[0];
```

But the best way is to add an id attribute to the div:

```
<div id="about" class="about">
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I missed that, will mark as correct once limit is up!

Answer (score 3):

You are using getElementById but there is no element with id = "about"

Ty to:

```
<body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <div class="SlideContent">
    <div id="about" class="about">
    <div class="home">
      <div class="TxtC">
        <div class="ctxt">
          <div class="TextHead">
            Scaledish 
          </div>
          <div class="TextBodyTW">
            <a onclick='on()'>About</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And on that same line you're missing a closing angle bracket.

Comment: And i think it should be `onclick="off()"` since `#about` style is already `block` (:

Comment: Thanks, Everyone! big help, don't know how I missed that